# "com.whatsapp" folder repeatedly and automatically getting deleted

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, android-13

I have an Oppo Reno 8 Pro (Android 13).

Since switching from my Huawei phone, the folder with the received and sent images/videos in the internal storage gets cleaned automatically every 3-4 days. As a result all my received and sent media are gone.

I can use an old backup, and that restores images/videos for a while, but after a couple of days they get deleted again.

How do I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: You might want to check the installed File Managers and Gallery apps, and whether they have a feature to auto-clean storage or media files specifically, regardless if they have been backed up or not. Usually they have a setting to ignore certain folders.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I checked it but i dont think thats the problem. I cant find any settings like this. My brother has the same phone and not this issue :(